# Convert Mac OS Extended (Journaled) Time Machine contents to APFS

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, time-machine, restore

[image: Screenshot]

Clicking on any of the dates on the right hand side, as shown in the picture, doesn't do anything. What might be the issue here?

[image: Screenshot]

I can access Applications perfectly fine though. The others are greyed out.

I think it's because the old computer was Mac OS Extended (Journaled) whereas the new computer is APFS. Is there a way to convert the contents of the time machine to APFS?

Comment: No,there is noway to convert be time machine

Answer (score 1):

If clicking the date doesn't move to that date, it's because there is no backup *for that selected location*. It doesn't mean there's no backup at all.

See this image…

[image]

I have backups only for my boot drive. Other drives have been removed from Time Machine's backup prefs. If I start from 'Now' then all the drives show in the list on the left. As soon as I scroll back, then the other drives grey out, because there's no data [Acronis is an NTFS volume & Time Machine doesn't know what to do with that].

So, to see what's really there, start from your boot volume & go backwards from there. At each step some locations may grey out, but the boot drive itself should have data going back in time.